# Razor expression in Inline javascript parsing error

Tags: javascript, razor

I am writing in Visual Studio 2012 (Visual Basic) ASP.NET MVC4 project.

Here is my piece of code:

```
<input type="button" value="EDIT" onclick="MngMCRItem('@Url.Action("EditMCRItem", "MCRForm", Nothing)', {doc_id : '@Model.DOC_ID', item_id : @itm.ITEM_ID_IN_DOC}, this.value)"/>
```

This code causes the editor show error

> Unterminated string constant. Expected ')'.

Are there any better way to rewrite my code? Thank you in advance for every advice.

**EDIT** 
Currently, I have Resharper 8.2.1 with Visual Studio 2013 the problem has gone.

Comment: What is the purpose of `enter code here` ?

Comment: Sorry for that stuff code, this post is my first post here. So, I forget to delete it after using the StackOverFlow tool.

Comment: well you just use series of single and double quotes which generates this error just because of incorrect format of using it.

Comment: @Joker please see the comment which I have answered to Alex below. I provided the clearer snippet.

Comment: yeah you have provided the answer, that's why I just commented here didn't post the same answer as yours. Hopefully you got my point

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with double quotes and single quotes here:

```
onclick="MngMCRItem('@Url.Action("EditMCRItem", "MCRForm", Nothing)'
```

You open double quote here -> `"MngMCRItem('@Url.Action("` <- here it's closed
so the next part of the command can not be understood...

Comment: Art, thanks for your suggestion, but this problem is not occurred in `<script>` tag like this snippet:
    `<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function onload() {
    MCRns.AutoComplete("MAT_CODE", "@Url.Action("GetMATERIAL_JSON", "MCRForm", Nothing)");
    MCRns.AutoComplete("PURCHASE_GRP", "@Url.Action("GetPURCHASE_GRP_JSON", "MCRForm", Nothing)");
    }
    );
    </script>`

Moreover, I have tried changing the Razor expression to be:
    `<input type="button" value="ADD MCR ITEM" onclick="MngMCRItem('@1234')" />`
but the problem is still being there.

Comment: You are making the same mistake in your comment!!!
"@Url.Action("GetMATERIAL_JSON", "MCRForm", Nothing)"); - this is wrong!!!
<input type="button" value="ADD MCR ITEM" onclick="MngMCRItem('1234')" /> - this should work you probably have an error at some other place

Answer (score 0):

@Alex Art, did you try putting my snippet into the Visual Studio editor and see what is going on? From that context, I am confident that I did NOT make the mistake. So, I will provide the clearer snippet below and I think this is easily obvious.

```
@Code
  Dim testing As String = "Hello World!"
End Code

<script type="text/javascript">
  var test = {
    foo : '@Html.Hidden("helloWorld", testing)', // This is perfectly OK
    bar : 'testing'
  };
</script>

<input type="text" name="inpTesting" value="test" onclick="alert('@testing');" /> <!--ERROR in inline js-->
<input type="text" name="inpTesting" value="" onclick="alert('Hello World!');" /> <!--Server-Compiled(result) Code when using some browser 'view page source'-->
```

Comment: I didn't write the comment continue to @Alex's post because of showing result is not well-formatted.